# What game systems exist which uses camera input?

Tags: camera, image

The group and I is in the middle of a semester project where we are currently researching on which game systems are using camera as input or as an interactive medium?
We would like some help listing some of the game systems which uses camera input, as it seems hard to find other examples. 
Currently we know that webcam browser games uses camera input ([Newgrounds webcam games](http://www.newgrounds.com/game/webcamgames)), as well as the xbox kinect.
I know this questions seems rather vague, though I still hope some people is capable of helping.

Comment: I think this would be better suited for gaming SE?

Comment: The reasearch we are trying to do is going into a report about the development of a game, so we though it was probably best to place to ask the question here. (And is gaming SE isn't more for ingame related issues?)

Comment: Kinect, the fastest selling consumer electronics device. Easy to find a lot about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PS3 (Playstation eye) and PS2 (Eyetoy) also use camera input.  I believe the PS2 was the first console to do this.

Technically the Wii also uses camera input, as the wiimote has a camera in it to handle the pointer input style, but I don't think that's the sort of thing you're talking about.

Comment: Within the wii, isn't the camera tracking just a infrared reciever? Also thanks for the reply, forgot all about those playstation games.

Comment: Yeah, the camera in the wiimote is infrared only.  By default it only reads the infrared LEDs in the sensor bar, but if you're clever enough you can do some [amazing things](http://www.ted.com/talks/johnny_lee_demos_wii_remote_hacks.html) with it.

Comment: Yeah okay, thanks for the answer - Noted your suggestions